# Mysql where in not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 

`tests`.`id`, 
`tests`.`created_at`, 
`tests`.`updated_at`, 
`tests`.`created_by`, 
`tests`.`date_of_test`, 
`tests`.`location`, 
`tests`.`information`, 
`tests`.`title`, 
`tests`.`goals`, 
`tests`.`deleted_at`, 
`tests`.`status`, 
`tests`.`tester`, 
`tests`.`test_approach`

FROM `tests`

WHERE

`tests`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `test_wobble`.`test_id`
    FROM `project_wobble`
    INNER JOIN `wobbles` ON `project_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `wobble_profiles` ON `wobble_profiles`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `wobble_profile_user` ON `wobble_profile_user`.`wobble_profile_id` = `wobble_profiles`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `test_wobble` ON `test_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
    WHERE `project_wobble`.`project_id` = '2' AND `wobble_profile_user`.`user_id` = '3'
    GROUP BY `wobbles`.`id`
) 

GROUP BY `tests`.`id`
ORDER BY tests.date_of_test DESC
```

If I run the `IN` query on its own, it returns

- **1** result
- with the value **13**.
- the column is called `"test_id"`

When i run the whole above query, I get

- **2** results from the test table back...
- with different ids... **13** and **14**.

If I replace the `IN` query with the number **13**... The SQL returns **1** result (**The correct one**).

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT `test_wobble`.`test_id`
FROM `project_wobble`
INNER JOIN `wobbles` ON `project_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profiles` ON `wobble_profiles`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profile_user` ON `wobble_profile_user`.`wobble_profile_id` = `wobble_profiles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `test_wobble` ON `test_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
WHERE `project_wobble`.`project_id` = '2' AND `wobble_profile_user`.`user_id` = '3'
GROUP BY `wobbles`.`id`
```

groups by `wobbles.id` but returns `test_wobble.test_id` which is not a part of `GROUP BY`.

On each iteration, `MySQL` pushes the IN field into this query:

```
SELECT `test_wobble`.`test_id`
FROM `project_wobble`
INNER JOIN `wobbles` ON `project_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profiles` ON `wobble_profiles`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profile_user` ON `wobble_profile_user`.`wobble_profile_id` = `wobble_profiles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `test_wobble` ON `test_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
WHERE `project_wobble`.`project_id` = '2' AND `wobble_profile_user`.`user_id` = '3'

-- This is implicitly added by MySQL when optimizing
AND `test_wobble`.`test_id` = `tests`.`id`
GROUP BY `wobbles`.`id`
```

and then just checks if some value exists.

If you remove the `GROUP BY` from your `IN` query, you'll see that it contains both `13` and `14`, but only one of those is returned when you run the query with `GROUP BY`.

You can also try running the second query, substituting 13 and 14 instead of `tests.id` and make sure the query returns something in both cases.

This might actually be considered a bug in `MySQL`. However, since the documentation does not specify which ungrouped and unaggregated expression will be returned from a grouped query, it's better to specify it explicitly, of side effects from the optimizer will kick in like the do in this case.

Could you please provide some sample of your data and outline what are you going to achieve with the query?

Comment: I found the issue, but you were the one who helped me find it! I had deleted column denoting trashed items... but was searching across them anyway... I ended up adding where is null on the deleted_at column of one of the inside joins.. problemmo solved!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: well... my pleasure, but your query is still written in a non-deterministic way, so expect more bugs to pop up. Just a heads up!

Comment: In fact, the documentation [specifies it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) very clear: *"the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"*.

Comment: @Quassnoi - no it's not, i changed it to reflect your way bro. lol. it's all good and awesome now :)(

Comment: @axiac - it's all good bro, i got it sorted, i copied the above and absorbed everything said, i changed the query... but the main issue was the deleted at aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit hard to tell without knowing what the data is.  But, you do have an issue in the subquery.  This is your subquery:

```
SELECT `test_wobble`.`test_id`
FROM `project_wobble` INNER JOIN
      `wobbles`
      ON `project_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id` INNER JOIN
      `wobble_profiles`
      ON `wobble_profiles`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id` INNER JOIN
      `wobble_profile_user`
      ON `wobble_profile_user`.`wobble_profile_id` = `wobble_profiles`.`id` INNER JOIN
      `test_wobble`
      ON `test_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
WHERE `project_wobble`.`project_id` = '2' AND `wobble_profile_user`.`user_id` = '3'
GROUP BY `wobbles`.`id`
```

Note the `select` and `group by`.  These have different variables:

```
`test_wobble`.`test_id`
`wobbles`.`id`
```

I'm not sure which one you really want.  But MySQL returns an *indeterminate* value when you run the query -- and a value that can change from one run to the next.  You should fix the `select` and `group by` so they match.

Comment: But the Where In must return only 1 select column?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 . . . Yes.  Subqueries used with `in` should only return one column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 a, 2 b) q WHERE (a, b) IN (SELECT 1, 2)`: this works for me

Comment: @Quassnoi . . . That works in some databases, but the OP appears to only want to compare one value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sure, it's just that subqueries used with IN should return exactly as many columns as there are in the tuple you're applying it to (which is not necessarily one).

Answer (score 0):

The inner query exposes undefined behaviour. It is explained in the documentation on the page [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

According to the SQL standard, the inner query is invalid. To be valid, all the columns that appear in the `SELECT`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` clauses must satisfy one of the following:

- they appear in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- are used (in `SELECT`, `HAVING` or `ORDER BY`) only as parameters of [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- are functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` columns.

For example, using your tables, you can put in the `SELECT` clause:

- `wobbles.id` - because it appears in the `GROUP BY` clause;
- `COUNT(DISTINCT project_wobble.project_id)` - even if `project_wobble.project_id` does not appear in `GROUP BY`, it can be used as a parameter of the aggregate function [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct);
- any column of table `wobbles`, given that the column `id` is its `PK` - all the columns of table `wobbles` are functionally dependent on `wobbles.id` (their values are uniquely determined by the value of `wobbles.id`).

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL accepts queries that do not follow the above requirements but, as the documentation states:

> In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

Starting with version 5.7.5, MySQL implements detection of functional dependence as an configurable feature (which is turned ON by default).

On 5.7.5 your inner query will trigger an error and that's all; your query is invalid, so it doesn't run at all.

On previous versions (also on 5.7.5 if the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is disabled), the query runs but its results are unpredictable. They can change from one execution to the next if, for example, a row is deleted then re-inserted.

Because the MySQL query optimizer re-organizes your whole query for better execution plan, when it is embedded in the larger query its execution is not the same as when it is ran standalone. This is another way you can observe its undefined behaviour.

#### How to fix your query

Extract the inner query, remove the `GROUP BY` clause, add more columns to the `SELECT` clause and look at what it produces:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `test_wobble`.`wobble_id`, `test_wobble`.`test_id`
FROM `project_wobble`
INNER JOIN `wobbles` ON `project_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profiles` ON `wobble_profiles`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `wobble_profile_user` ON `wobble_profile_user`.`wobble_profile_id` = `wobble_profiles`.`id`
INNER JOIN `test_wobble` ON `test_wobble`.`wobble_id` = `wobbles`.`id`
WHERE `project_wobble`.`project_id` = '2' AND `wobble_profile_user`.`user_id` = '3'
```

If I'm not wrong, it will produce two rows having the same `wobble_id` and values `13` and `14` for column `test_id`.

If this result set is correct then you can remove `test_wobble.wobble_id` from `SELECT`, keep `DISTINCT` and put the query into the larger one.

There is no need for `GROUP BY` (because of the `DISTINCT`) and it should work faster without it.